# Proxy Camera Stream to Server

Tags: camera, server

The camera runs fine locally, using MJPG-Streamer to broadcast the stream. However I'm trying to setup the stream to be relayed via a server rather than opening any ports on the router from the local network. With the amount of traffic the stream may get I'm not too sure the Pi would be able to handle the load on its own anyway.

What's the best method for creating the link between the Pi and the remote server? We will need to output the stream in a HTML5 player, so we won't be able to use any services like Ustream.